# Algorithms that approximate the volume of concave/convex hull formed by some n-dimensional data points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms, geometric-topology, computational-geometry

Suppose now I have 1000 d-dimensional data points. Is there a convenient algorithm that can approximate the volume of the concave/convex hull formed by these points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, depends on what you mean by convinient. For large d, unless there is some other structure you can take advantage of I would probably just use a Monte Carlo simulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_volume_approximation), given a membership oracle, we can compute an $\epsilon$ approximation of the volume of the convex hull in polynomial time in $n$ (=1000), $d$ and $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Combining with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731437), it seems that membership can also be tested fairly quickly.
However, if this is convenient enough for you, I don't know.